# Warning statement in C++ (Beginner)

Tags: c++, warnings

I was just trying a few things out, as I am just starting with C++. I don't get the following error statement:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string& s6(string a) {return a;}
int main() {

    string a = "helloo";

    s6(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Then I get the following warning:

```
Untitled.cpp:4:30: warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'a' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
string& s6(string a) {return a;}
                             ^
1 warning generated.
```

What does this exactly mean?

Comment: It exactly means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 3):

What that message means is that you are returning a reference to a local variable, and that's bad and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Local variables, like variables declared inside functions, but *also* arguments to functions, are local to the function and are destructed when they go out of scope (the function returns). If you return a reference to a local variable, when the function returns you will have a reference to some object that no longer exists.

Comment: very helpfull, thanks :)